# How to delete branches from specific repository of azure devops in bulk quantity?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have one repository in Azure DevOps called **"Test-Repo"**. Which contains **10** different branches.

As per my exploration, We can use command `az repos ref delete --name $branchName --object-id $objectId --organization $organizationURL --project $projectName --repository $repoName`

My requirement was I want to delete the specific 3 branches i.e. branch 2,5,7 from my 10 branches.

I have written PowerShell script which will initially shows you repo and branch information which shows you output in table which contains **branch name** and **branch objectId**. After that use will manually give the input of branch name and objectId from that output. and It will delete the branch. Which is successful.

Following is my PowerShell script.

```
$projectName= "xyz"
$organizationURL= "https://dev.azure.com/xyz"
$repoList= az repos list --organization $organizationURL --project $projectName 
$repoList= $repoList | ConvertFrom-Json
$repoNames= $repoList.name

 

function getRepositories {
    Write-Output "Repositories available in the $projectName project"
    foreach ($repo in $repoNames) {
        Write-Output "  $($repoNames.IndexOf($repo)+1)-$($repo)"
    }
}
getRepositories;

 

$repoNumber = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter repo number to list its branches";
$repoNumber = $repoNumber - 1;
$repoName= "$($repoNames[$repoNumber])"
Write-Output $repoName;

$branchInfo = az repos ref list --organization $organizationURL --project $projectName --repository $repoName
$branchInfo = $branchInfo | ConvertFrom-Json

$branchInfo = $branchInfo | Format-Table -Property name, objectId;
Write-Output $branchInfo;

$branchName = Read-Host "Enter the name of branch you wish to delete"
$branchId = Read-Host "Enter the ObjectID of branch you wish to delete"

Write-Host "Deleteing branch $branchName from $repoName repository..!!" -ForegroundColor red;

az repos ref delete --name $branchName --object-id $branchId --organization $organizationURL --project $projectName --repository $repoName;
Write-Host "Success...!"
```

Now my question is,

***a. How to give index to my table which shows branch name and branch objectId?***

***b. Is is possible to get exact branch objectId using branch name? If yes, How?***

***c. How to take multiple index no.s as inputs from user to delete that index-specified branches?***

Answer (score 0):

**Please call rest API to list your branches follow this page: [Refs-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)**

To get the exact branch objectId, please specify the `filterContains={branch-name}` URI parameter like below:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0&filterContains={branch-name}
```

Here are the results on my side:
[image]

**Please call this API to delete branches in your repository: [Create/Update/Delete a ref by repositoryId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#create/update/delete-a-ref-by-repositoryid)**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0
```

The request body should be a JSON format like below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "{the-branch-name1}",
    "oldObjectId": "{the-id-you-want-to-delet-in-the-last-api-results}",
    "newObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  },
  {
    "name": "{the-branch-name2}",
    "oldObjectId": "{the-id-you-want-to-delet-in-the-last-api-results}",
    "newObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  },
]
```

After seeing the result like below, you could find that branches you want to delete have been deleted already:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I already fetched branch name and objectID sucessfully. Just want to know that How can I get exact branch objectId by using branch name.